# Validate Page Title in Admin Dashboard Orchard CMS

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, orchardcms, dashboard

Is there an easy solution to have custom validation for out-of-the box fields, e.g. Page Title in admin dashboard should be less than 100 characters. I know how to do that in custom module and how to do that with modifying the Orchard.CMS source, but I'm hesitating that it is the right solution.

Comment: I don't see an easy way to do this today without replacing the title part (or routable pre-1.4)

Comment: The reason I'm asking, that there are plenty of out of the box fields and I don't want to rewrite the core part, so it should be easy to update to future version of orchard cms. I guess you understand me. Anyway thanks for the comment. At least I know that there is no quick and clear solution

Comment: We want eventually for all admin forms to use shapes like the front end, which would make this a lot easier, but for the moment that's what it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, actually you might be able to pull it off by adding a driver to the one that already exists and have that render some validation code. You can after all have more than one driver for any part. I'm pretty sure that would work. Worth trying anyways.